# Taking input data from the server while using Appium to automate iOS app?

Tags: appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios, appium-android

I have a requirement that I need to fetch login credentials input from another desktop server and currently we are using Appium for iOS mobile app automation . How to integrate this with Appium? Is this possible? Or any alternative ways along with Appium? Any internet example could be great help.

Answer (score 0):

You would have your language of choice read the variable from a file or  stream. How you get it to those places is up to you and outside the realm of Appium per se and dependent on how your server functions. Without more detail, no more help can be provided.

Comment: 1. Is it possible to use two Drivers like ChromeDriver and AppiumDriver/iOSDriver in same script? 2. ChomeDriver to invoke web page to read Test data on desktop and returning to mobile device using iOSdriver. is this possible?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You'd write the code the same way you'd do so separately, but together. Both drivers would be able to read and write the same objects.